# Application is enabled only to Portrait, but UIImagePickerController rotates in iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

**Please note that the answer below - do not work for iOS6 so I still need an answer!**

My application is enabled only for Portrait mode.

However, if I embed a UIImagePickerController inside as a subview, and rotate the device, the top and bottom bar stays in the same location, however UIImagePickerController does rotate.

How can I prevent it from rotating?

This is the code:

```
    [self.view.window addSubview:self.imagePickerController.view];
    self.imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO; 
    self.imagePickerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 90, 320, 320);
    self.imagePickerController.allowsEditing = NO;
```

**EDITED**

I am using iOS6 where shouldAutorotate is not being calle

Comment: Please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538041/uiimagepickercontroller-camera-preview-is-portrait-in-landscape-app

Answer (score 12):

Add this `UIImagePickerController` category in your class,

```
@interface UIImagePickerController(Nonrotating)
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate;
@end

@implementation UIImagePickerController(Nonrotating)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

  return NO;
}

@end
```

Comment: What do you mean by adding in your class? Could it be a separate file? if so - how do I refer to it?

Comment: It doesn't work. When I rotate the iPhone, also the UIImagePickerController rotates. It doesn't listen to any of the methods

Comment: @Odelya Did you add UIImagePickerControllerDelegate on .h file??

Comment: Sure! didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo is being called after capturing an image

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775265/ios-6-shouldautorotate-is-not-being-called will help me

Comment: Would you like to fix your answer so I could choose it? Since I don't understand how to use willRotateToInterfaceOrientation

Comment: @Odelya I didn't use this willRotateToInterfaceOrientation before.. I will try.. Did you check you have deleted unwanted orientations from info.plist.?

Answer (score 2):

include the following in your controller this will work, I'm just creating the category of `UIImagePickerController`

```
@interface UIImagePickerController (private)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate;
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation;
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations;
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation;

@end


@implementation UIImagePickerController (Private)

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{  
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
@end
```

Comment: just past it in your ViewController.m file before the @implementation.

Comment: Do you mean that I can simply create 2 files h. and m., locate them anywhere in the project and it will work?

Comment: no no, include it in that controller where you are implementing the imagePickerController

Comment: It doesn't work. When I rotate the iPhone, also the UIImagePickerController rotates. It doesn't listen to any of the methods

Comment: It does stop on method supportedInterfaceOrientations (in breakpoint) but only when it  is opened.

Comment: It doesn't stop on shouldAutorotate or any other

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775265/ios-6-shouldautorotate-is-not-being-called will help me

Comment: You want to edit the answer to ios6 so I could mark it as true?

Comment: Well this is the question - I tried to add this method but it didn't work for me. I am looking for an answer that will work in iOS6

Comment: Don't you need an "@end" at the end of implementation as well?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to override the

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation;
```

method of `UIImagePickerController`. I'm not sure if this is the best possibility but it will work.

So if you only want your UIImagePickerController to be rotated to portrait use the following code

```
@interface PortraitUIImagePickerController : UIImagePickerController

@end
```

And the implementation should look like the following

```
@implementation PortraitUIImagePickerController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation);
}

@end
```

Comment: I am using iOS6 and shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

The category in the most voted answer works, but since it is discouraged to use categories, you can also make a subclass of UIImagePickerController and use that.

If you want to avoid rotating of the UIImagePickerController add the following class

UINonRotatableImagePickerController.h

```
@interface UINonRotatableImagePickerController : UIImagePickerController

@end
```

UINonRotatableImagePickerController.m

```
@implementation UINonRotatableImagePickerController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

@end
```

You have to change the UIImagePicker class in the storyboard to use UILandscapeImagePickerController, or if you allocate it in code, change

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
```

to

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UINonRotatableImagePickerController alloc] init];
```

and include UINonRotatableImagePickerController.h in your code.

Comment: imagePicker is Always Portrait and never support subclassing, It rotates only if image picker is added as subview because it rotates because of superview, not itself.

Comment: Maybe that is the case for the iPhone, but I have my fullscreen imagepicker in landscape for the iPad.