# Can't set size of UIPopoverController on device rotation change

Tags: size, orientation, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

In my iPad app, I am recording a video (`UIImagePickerController` in a `UIPopoverController`).

The problem is that when I change the orientation of the device, the size of the `UIPopoverController` reduces to 320x480 (for portrait) and 480x320 (for landscape). Surprisingly, the exact same dimensions (600x880) are working fine when I create it, but not when I rotate it.

Here is how I am initializing:

```
self.popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePicker];
popover.delegate = self;
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(109, 590, 550,500) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];//recordProtocolBtn.frame
    [self.popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(600, 880)];
}
else {
    [self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(750, 110, 550, 600) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];
    [self.popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(600, 600)];
}
```

In rotation to Portrait:

```
[self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
[self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(109, 590, 550,500) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
[self.popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(600, 880)];
```

And in rotation to landscape:

```
[self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
[self.popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(750, 110, 550, 600) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];
[self.popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(600, 600)];
```

Comment: @downvoter you don't need to down vote if your brain is too tiny to comprehend some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did is not strictly a solution but a workaround.

I disabled the orientation change notifications from firing when I presented the `UIPopoverController` and enabled them when I dismissed it, [using help from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10161273/1276636).

This way the app works smoothly because I think the users won't like the app to rotate during video recording.